# How to fetch data after successfull login in json?

Tags: identityserver4

How do you fetch logged in user data in form of json. I know a /diagnostics shows data in html i.e email, phone number, username. How do i curl to get this data in json. What is the url eg https://demo.identityserver.io/diagnostics where i can run a command to fetch the data. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the IdentityServer built-in userinfo endpoint using the provided access token that you received after the user authenticated. The data you get back is in JSON.

see the documentation here https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/reference/endpoints/userinfo/